# Call Intent in Fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am making an intent call in a fragment . All though i updated with the intent documentation it is not working.This is the process i did...

First the manifest i added...

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged" />
```

Then i added this code...

```
 private  void hacerLlamada(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(telefono.trim()));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
        }
        else
        {

            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error Log]

[image: Debugg]

What should i do for this to work . the fragment is attached to the mainActivity.

Comment: don't post text as image

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i dont undestand what you mean

Comment: You posted stacktrace as image. Don't. Copy and paste as text next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is due to Uri.parse(). Please change your Uri.parse to
`Uri.parse("tel:" + telefono.trim())`